# How to properly set LUN IDs for multiple targets

Tags: freebsd, iscsi, truenas

I'm running iSCSI to share multiple iSCSI targets via FreeNAS. Since I'm new to iSCSI I'm concerned I have the LUN IDs or other settings setup incorrectly.

Here's how I'm connecting:

- I'm running globalSAN Initiator on the connecting Mac Mini (mac-data).
- I'm running the built-in iSCSI Initiator in Windows 2012 R2 running in Parallels VM on Mac Mini (starscream-backup)
- I'm running the built-in iSCSI Initiator in Windows 8.1 in Parallels VM on Mac Pro (bonecrusher-data and bonecrusher-backup)

Should there be a unique LUN ID for each Target-Extent combination?

Or, should there be a unique LUN ID for each Target?

Or, is there some other rule one should be following when assigning LUN IDs?

Here is my FreeNAS server iSCSI config:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it not working?

Comment: It is working most of the time, but I'm experiencing several unexplainable issues from various clients (too varied to go into here), so I thought I'd verify my configuration is correct since I cannot find the root cause of the various other issue. Do you know if there should be a unique LUN ID for each target? In my case, that would mean 0, 1, 2, and 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to mount different devices (extents) to the same host, the corresponding LUNs should have unique IDs. In another case, you can end up facing various weird issues when remounting datastores / CSVs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So each target-extent needs to be unique, but LUN Ids can be reused in other target-extent combinations? If so, then my configuration as shown in my question is correct?